# How do I make this animation go counterclockwise?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibezierpath, caanimation

I have already got part of my animation completed. What I am trying to do is create the line border animation like [this](http://makeagif.com/5p6qal), where the line travels across the top and right side of the rectangle. What I need in addition to this is creating another line that mirrors the line shown in the video (traveling across the left side then bottom of the rectangle),counterclockwise. I tried doing this using the -bezierPathByReversingPath(_:) function, but it made the origin for the line begin in the bottom left of the rectangle. I am not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated!
Here’s my code:

```
// Create layer
rightLine = CAShapeLayer()
rightLine.bounds = centerButton.bounds
rightLine.position = view.center
rightLine.path = UIBezierPath(rect: rightLine.bounds).CGPath
rightLine.lineWidth = 3
rightLine.strokeColor = UIColor(hex: "3D424E").CGColor
rightLine.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
rightLine.strokeStart = 0
rightLine.strokeEnd = 0

// Create animation
let rightStart = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
rightStart.toValue = 0
let rightEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
rightEnd.toValue = 0.5

rightLineGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
rightLineGroup.animations = [rightStart, rightEnd]
rightLineGroup.duration = 1.5
rightLineGroup.autoreverses = true
rightLineGroup.repeatCount = HUGE // repeat forever

self.view.layer.addSublayer(rightLine)
rightLine.addAnimation(rightLineGroup, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: Did you try negative values for the strokeStart/rightStart?

Comment: Nope. `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` are only permissible from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Animating `strokeStart` from zero to zero does nothing.

You probably want to leave `strokeEnd` at `1.0` (the default) and animate `strokeStart` from `1.0` to `0.5`. That should have the desired effect.